# When does a persistent object become detached

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Could somebody help me understand with an example when exactly a persistent object becomes a detached object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It becomes detached when:

1. you explicitly call .detach()
2. close the session
3. close the entity manager

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the persistence context you are using (transaction or extended). See [this link](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jpa/object_lifecycle.html) for a description. Basically as per the other answer EXCEPT that answer misses off detachment when a transaction is committed when using transaction PersistenceContext

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best understanding on when the entity is **detached** is looking at what JPA specification says about entity's lifecycle.

> A detached entity instance is an instance with a persistent identity that is not (or no longer) associated with a persistence context.

This means that an entity may be considered as detached even it is newly created. Let's say that our entity `A` has its id marked as `@Id @GeneratedValue`. So basically the JPA provider will take care of assigning an id. But if you will specify `A`'s id explicitly (e.g. `a.setId(1)`) and then pass it to `persist()` you will get an Exception.